# Update a github repository secret from a github action

Tags: github-actions, secret-key

I have a website fetching the facebook events of one of my webpage thanks to a [ruby script](https://github.com/atelierdesmedias/atelierdesmedias.github.io/blob/main/events.rb).

The script is executed within a github action before the build.

Unfortunately, the facebook token has a limited validity. I managed to find a way to renew it but I'm wondering if it is possible to update my `FACEBOOK_TOKEN` repository secret from a Github action ?

Of course I'm open to alternative like finding a way to have a permanent token!

Comment: Did you try using actions from the marketplace? Such as this one: https://github.com/marketplace/actions/set-action-secret?

Comment: @GuiFalourd This looks like a good start. It is not very clear if the `value` can be obtained from a script I run (in my case the one who generate the new facebook token)

Comment: You could eventually print the value in your script to set it in a workflow variable to use it later somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [`actions/github-script@v6`](https://github.com/actions/github-script) action you can do this very easily through the actions [API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/secrets?apiVersion=2022-11-28#create-or-update-a-repository-secret). You will also need a custom personal access token with the `repo` scope.

```yaml
jobs:
  update-token:
    env:
      GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GHPAT_TOKEN || github.token }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: 20
      - run: |
          npm install --global sodium-native@4.0.4
          echo "NODE_PATH=$(npm root -g)" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Update FB Token
        uses: actions/github-script@v6
        env:
          FACEBOOK_TOKEN: ${{ 'REPLACE ME WITH TOKEN' }}
        with:
          result-encoding: string
          github-token: ${{ env.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          script: |
            const sodium = require('sodium-native');
            const { data: {key: publicKey, key_id: keyId} } = await github.rest.actions.getRepoPublicKey({...context.repo});
            if (publicKey) {
              const key = Buffer.from(publicKey, 'base64');
              const message = Buffer.from(process.env.FACEBOOK_TOKEN);
              const ciphertext = Buffer.alloc(message.length + sodium.crypto_box_SEALBYTES);

              sodium.crypto_box_seal(ciphertext, message, key);
              const encryptedToken = ciphertext.toString('base64');

              await github.rest.actions.createOrUpdateRepoSecret({
                ...context.repo, 
                secret_name: 'FACEBOOK_TOKEN',
                encrypted_value: encryptedToken,
                key_id: keyId,
              });
            } else {
              core.error('Failed to fetch the public key. Unable to update secret');
            }
```

See the docs on [Encrypting secrets for the REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/encrypting-secrets-for-the-rest-api?apiVersion=2022-11-28).

---

Note: In order to continue to have `FACEBOOK_TOKEN` be a secret, you might want to mask it's content either by using the [`::add-mask::...`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#masking-a-value-in-a-log) command, or using `core.setSecret('token content')`.

Comment: I did something equivalent in ruby but it didn't worked really well because the facebook token was still expiring for an unknown reason. I finally disabled the use of the facebook api so I didn't test your code.